# How do I show that a function is continuous in topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $(X,T_1)$ and $(Y,T_2)$ be topological spaces and $z\in Y$ and define $f(x) = z$ for all $x\in X$

How do I show that $f(x)$ is continuous?

$f(x)$ is continuous at x at if $f(x) = y \in O$ where $O \in T_2$, then $\exists G \in T_1$ such that $f(G)\subseteq O$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My impression is that you need to understand the very definition better to solve this problem:

**Hint:** A function $f: (X, \tau_1) \to (Y, \tau_2)$ is called *continuous* if the preimage of any open set $V$ in $Y$ (i.e. $V \in \tau_2$) is an open subset of $X$, so you only need to check the condition:

$$\forall V \in \tau_2: f^{-1}(V) \in \tau_1$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that the inverse image of any $T_2$-open subset of $Y$ is a $T_1$-open subset of $X$.

Let $U \in T_2$.

Now $f(x) = z, \:\:\forall x \in X$, so

$$
f^{-1}[U] =
\begin{cases}
X,  & \text{if}\:\: z \in U \\
\emptyset, & \text{if}\:\: z \not \in U
\end{cases}
$$

In either case $f^{-1}[U]$ is an open subset of $X$ since $X$ and $\emptyset$ belong to $T_1$.